# How to format a string to replace all existing number inside a string to prefix with leading zero using regex

Tags: regex, string

Anyone knows how to use regex to convert a string with characters and numbers to prefix with leading zero for each occurance of a number inside the string.

Eg  ABC123 -> ABC000100020003

```
BCD02 - > BCD00000002

CD1A2 - > CD0001A0002
```

i.e for each occurance of a number it will prefix with leading zeros (total 4 digit for each occurance of a number)
Other characters to remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

search `/(\d)/g`

and replace with `000\1`

will do it.

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/aB8iE9

javascript demo here:

```
var str = "ABC123";
var res = str.replace(/(\d)/g, '000$1');
console.log(res);
```